# Silverlight 3 and Silverlight 4 Coexistance

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I work on several projects with different development environments.  I would like to maintain a Visual Studio 2008/Silverlight 3 environment on the same development workstation as a Visual Studio 2010/Silverlight 4 environment.  If possible, I would like to be able to work on both at the same time, without using virtual machines.

Has anyone done that successfully?  Is there anything special I need to do to help them coexist?  I previously installed Silverlight 4, and it prevented me from working in the Visual Studio 2008/Silverlight 3 environment.  But it is possible that I did something wrong in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the two can coexist next to each other.  You will either need to make a VM with the specified configuration, or specify the SL version in Visual Studio.

Can you ellaborate why you can't run you SL3 project in VS 2008?

Comment: Sorry, I can't.  I wish I had written the error messages down when it happened a month ago.  It took me most of an afternoon to remove Silverlight 4 from my system so that I could continue development in Silverlight 3, so I really don't want to go there again unless someone else has done it and knows how to keep them separate.  Otherwise, I will simply need to stay in the Silverlight 3 environment, as that project is far more important than the Silverlight 4/Visual Studio 2010 exploration I am doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use VS 2010 for your SL3 work?  VS 2010 includes multi-targeting capabilities, and is compatible with Silverlight 3 out of the box.  SL4 support is added with the SL4 development tools, so at that point it supports both.

You can pick which Silverlight version you want each project to be either at project creation time (for new projects), or in the project Properties (for existing projects).